# Logic Error with object from JSONArray

Tags: android, json

I try load the subject details but it only give the value from the first row of table(student) even I choose the different subject.

I have check the value of id that bring from the previous section. The id seems fine.

Please help me.

This is the code where I bring the value.

```
          // getting id from intent
       user_id= i.getStringExtra(TAG_USER_ID);
    TextView test = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.user_id);
    test.setText(user_id);
```

This is the code of JSON.

```
protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... args) {

        JSONObject json = null;     

        try {
                //Building parameters
                List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("user_id", user_id));

                json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url_subject_details, "GET", params);

                // check your log for json response
                Log.d("Single Subject Details", json.toString());
            }

        catch(Exception e)
            {
              e.printStackTrace();
            }   
        return json;

    }


protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject  json) {
        super.onPostExecute(json);
        // dismiss the dialog once product deleted
        pDialog.dismiss();


        try{
            // json success tag     
            int success;

            success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

            // successfully received subject details
            JSONArray studentObj = json.getJSONArray(TAG_STUDENT); // JSON Array

            // get subject object from JSON Array
            JSONObject subject = studentObj.getJSONObject(0);

            if (success == 1) {                                          
                txtName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputName);
                txtEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputEmail);

                // display subject data in EditText
                txtName.setText(subject.getString(TAG_NAME));
                txtEmail.setText(subject.getString(TAG_EMAIL)); 
            } else {

            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

This is JSONParser.java

```
public class JSONParser {

static InputStream is = null;
static JSONObject jObj = null;
static String json = "";

// constructor
public JSONParser() {

}

// function get json from url
// by making HTTP POST or GET mehtod
public JSONObject makeHttpRequest(String url, String method,
        List<NameValuePair> params) {

    // Making HTTP request
    try {

        // check for request method
        if(method == "POST"){
            // request method is POST
            // defaultHttpClient
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
            httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            is = httpEntity.getContent();

        }else if(method == "GET"){
            // request method is GET
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            String paramString = URLEncodedUtils.format(params, "utf-8");
            url += "?" + paramString;
            HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            is = httpEntity.getContent();
        }           


    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        is.close();
        json = sb.toString();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
    }

    // try parse the string to a JSON object
    try {
        jObj = new JSONObject(json);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
    }

    // return JSON String
    return jObj;

}
 }
```

Comment: What is your error or problem?

Comment: @PiYusHGuPtA when I bring the different id, it shows the details from first row of student table(student). the student table is from PHPMySQL

Comment: @PiYusHGuPtA, please help me, I really need your help

Answer (score 0):

you need to change here from

```
JSONObject subject = studentObj.getJSONObject(0);
```

to

```
for (int i = 0; i < studentObj.length(); i++) {
    JSONObject subject = studentObj.getJSONObject(i);

     name = c.getString(TAG_NAME);
     email = c.getString(TAG_EMAIL);

}
```

Also make String `name` and `email` globally.

Comment: sir, now it show details from the second row, even I select from the different id.

Comment: yes, I have post the id that I bring using intent. Then the id params through GET method.

Comment: Just check while posting `user_id` to server? Is it poster right `user_id`?

Comment: how I want to view the user_id that has pass to the server ?
I have echo it but it doesnt appear.

Comment: the logcat says `Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: Value 668 of type java.lang.Integer cannot be converted to JSONObject`

Comment: Means you are converting some int value to JSONObject.

Comment: Show me your json respnse.

Comment: @Dendi It is your class dear. I want to show JSON data which fetches from server when you have posted your user_id to server.

Comment: Something like this {
    "contacts": [
        {
                "id": "c200",
                "name": "Ravi Tamada",
                "email": "ravi@gmail.com",
                "address": "xx-xx-xxxx,x - street, x - country",
                "gender" : "male",
                "phone": {
                    "mobile": "+91 0000000000",
                    "home": "00 000000",
                    "office": "00 000000"
                }
        },
        
  ]
}

Comment: this sir `03-29 18:41:20.024: D/Single Subject Details(10039): {"student":[{"email":"ultra@yahoo.com","user_id":"123","name":"ultra","ic_no":"123"},{"email":"amran@yahoo.com","user_id":"1234","name":"amran","ic_no":"01234"}],"success":1}`

Comment: Looks like that your json is not valid dear.

Comment: which part sir ?
all of them ?

Comment: You can use `AsyncTask` and update your `UI` in `onPostExecute()` method of it which is `override` method of `AsyncTask`

Comment: But your JSON is not valid.

Comment: I have create a file with `AsyncTask`, but got some logic error because the value didnt appear. I will post the question and give the link to you.